# From an Ansible inventory file, is it possible to include variables from another file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My Ansible hosts file:

```
mybox.mydomain.com ansible_ssh_pass={{mypassword}}
```

The variable 'mypassword' is defined in a file "variables.yml":

```
mypassword = somepassword
```

Is there a way I can include the variables from "variables.yml" in my hosts file?  Otherwise when I try to run some Ansible command, I get the error

```
the field 'password' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'mypassword' is undefined
```

I'm asking this because ultimately I want to use a Vault encrypted variable from a .yml file (since that is the only way Vault encrypts individual variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `variables.yml` into `group_vars/all/variables.yml` near your inventory.

This will load everything in `variables.yml` as group variables for every host in your inventory.